# the relationship between graph G and Complement graph of G in adjacency matrix $(A)^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't have a good English But I try to say good information. I get names form Internet too.
fore example we have graph G and complement graph of G called H.
G is simple (with no loops and undirected).

now, If we get adjacency matrix $(A)^2$ of G and H is there any relationship between them?
Is there any way to get Graph G is we have graph H? Is it possible to gain 
Total sum of elements of matrix A(G)^2 with A(H) or $A(H)^2$

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Total sum of field of matrix"? The sum of the components of the matrix?

Comment: No. because my language is not good I do mistake. I mean "The individual items in a matrix are called its elements or entries" so the total sum of elements

Comment: If $G$ is simple (i.e., is undirected, with no loops or multiple edges), then $G$ is also the complement of $H$, so yes, you can find $G$ from $H$. However, there are many non-simple graphs that have $H$ as their complement. So if non-simple graphs are allowed, then you cannot recover $G$ from $H$.

Comment: Yes. G is simple( with no loops and undirected) and H is complement of G.  Is it possible to find $A(H)^2$